# Association Mining Weka Only 1

Tags: weka, data-mining, apriori, associate

I'm trying to apply associate mining using apriori with Weka on my data set that looks like

```
A B C
1 0 1
0 0 1
1 0 0
```

But it's only finding rules where its 0 while I only want rules where there are 1s

How can I get around this? I don't want it to look for rules where an absence of something indicates the absence of something else but rather the presence of A to indicate the presence of C for example.

Comment: The Weka implementation is very slow. You can check the SPMF data mining library (which I am the founder), which offers very fast implementations of algorithms like FPGrowth, and more than 100 other algorithms for itemset and pattern mining. It is the most comprehensive library for pattern mining. In some experiments  on the performance webpage of the SPMF website you can see that it can be much faster than Weka, Coron and other pattern mining libraries. Of if you want to use C++, there is some good implementations on FIMI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing 0s with missing values instead! If I recall correctly, this will then produce the desired results. But I haven't used this for a long time, because Weka is just so much slower than ELKI or SPMF. Weka would just die on my data sets, whereas the other two worked fine.